# How do you substitute group by's with left joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.deptid Dept, 
                c.id     Course, 
                t.startdate 
FROM   course c 
       LEFT JOIN section s 
              ON courseid = c.id 
       LEFT JOIN term t 
              ON termid = t.id 
                 AND t.startdate < '2011-4-1' 
GROUP  BY course 
HAVING t.startdate IS NULL 
ORDER  BY dept, 
          course;
```

and I need to get rid of the group by and aggregate functions by using only join or left join. The left join is creating an extra null row and I don't know how to account for that without group by. Any help on re-writing this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This code works. That is not the issue. The issue is I am not allowed to use a group by or any aggregate functions.

Comment: but i need the left joins to get the data I'm trying to select because normally I'd group by the course id based on the null values but I can't use group by @GordonLinoff

Comment: This is unclear; could you add a sample input and expected output?

Comment: how do you want to substitute the NULL values exactly?

Comment: Which table does startDate belong to? I'm assuming Term, but I can't possibly know.

Comment: I edited the code to make it a bit more clear @siride .

Comment: I'm trying to write a query that lists dept id and course id for all courses that have not been taught in any Term starting before 2011-4-1. @Leo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this fixes your problem, but this what your query should look like:

```
SELECT c.deptId as Dept, c.id as Course, startDate
FROM Course c LEFT JOIN
     Section s
     ON courseId = c.id LEFT JOIN
     Term t
     ON termId = t.id AND startDate < '2011-04-01'
WHERE startDate IS NULL
GROUP BY course
ORDER BY Dept, Course;
```

Here are the changes:

- The `distinct` is unnecessary because you are doing a `group by`
- The dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format (an ISO standard)
- The comparison for `NULL` date is moved to a `where` clause
- The `group by` statement uses the id column for course
- The column aliases are introduced by `as` (for readability)

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't help because I'm not allowed to use a group by

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a `group by` clause and your `having` clause should be a `where` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.deptid Dept, 
                c.id     Course, 
                t.startdate 
FROM   course c 
       LEFT JOIN section s 
              ON courseid = c.id 
       LEFT JOIN term t 
              ON termid = t.id 
                 AND t.startdate < '2011-04-01' 
WHERE  t.startdate IS NULL 
ORDER  BY dept, 
          course;
```

This will find all course selections that *don't* have a term.

Comment: I've tried this. the problem with this is that there are multiple sections in each course and one section could start before '2011-4-11' so the where clause picks ones where it is null when it needs to somehow group them but without group. it's a tricky question.